# Hibernate Getting Output from a Generic Cursor

Tags: hibernate

Need to get data out from oracle database using a complex procedure.  The output is a generic cursor.  i am using hibernate to fetch the output.   But the Result set does not have a mapping as it is not some table.  how can i fetch the data out from the cursor into my object.

Is there a  way i can get a resultset object below instead of a list ?
I can get a connection from Session factory and use callable statement.  is that good practice ?

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "CALL GetStocks(:stockCode)")
    .addEntity(Stock.class)
    .setParameter("stockCode", "7277");

List result = query.list();
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    Stock stock = (Stock)result.get(i);
    System.out.println(stock.getStockCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate provides a `ScrollableResults` to deal with the cursor. Here is an example from the [API docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-update).

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

ScrollableResults customers = session.getNamedQuery("GetCustomers")
    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
int count=0;
while ( customers.next() ) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);
    customer.updateStuff(...);
    if ( ++count % 20 == 0 ) {
        //flush a batch of updates and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

[Here](http://www.site.lalitbhatt.com/hibernate-query-language-hql) is another example.

Comment: Well for this you would have to Define the Customer Mapping object with some table Name telling which column is mapped to which column.... but my resultset is combination of multiple tables as a generic cursor...  Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);